# How do I search for a certain folder located inside the root directory?

Tags: command-line, directory, find, search

I'm specifically looking for the command equivalent of `sudo find / -name filename` for searching folders instead of files in the terminal. Suggestions with a better set of commands for achieving the same goal are also welcome.

Comment: `-type d`  (ie. look for directories)

Comment: Note: `sudo find / -name filename` will also find directories named `filename`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`sudo find / -type d -name folderName 2>/dev/null`

the `2>/dev/null` is just there to discard any errors

You can even use `-iname` instead on `-name` for case insensitive search if you need